# WRS2 package error in post hoc test "Error in smmcrit(df, ncol(con)) : C must be less than or equal to 28"

Tags: r, anova, posthoc, two-way, robust

I have an error called "Error in smmcrit(df, ncol(con)) : C must be less than or equal to 28" when using the WRS2 package and conducting a post hoc test after a 2-way ANOVA. Please see the example below. So far, I could not find the solution. (this problem has not ben posted and discussed elsewhere)

Example:

```
# Create the data frame
data <- data.frame(Date = c("2021.08","2021.08","2021.09","2021.09","2021.09","2021.10","2021.10","2021.10","2021.11","2021.11","2021.11","2021.11","2021.11","2021.12","2021.12","2022.01","2022.01","2022.01","2022.01","2022.08","2022.08","2022.08","2022.08","2022.08","2022.09","2022.09","2022.10","2022.10","2022.10","2022.11","2022.11","2022.11","2022.11","2022.11","2022.12","2022.12","2022.12","2022.12","2023.01","2023.01","2023.01","2023.01","2021.08","2021.08","2021.09","2021.09","2021.09","2021.10","2021.10","2021.10","2021.11","2021.11","2021.11","2021.11","2021.11","2021.12","2021.12","2022.01","2022.01","2022.01","2022.01","2022.08","2022.08","2022.08","2022.08","2022.08","2022.09","2022.09","2022.09","2022.09","2022.10","2022.10","2022.10","2022.10","2022.11","2022.11","2022.11","2022.11","2022.11","2022.12","2022.12","2022.12","2022.12","2023.01","2023.01","2023.01","2023.01"),
                   Species = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A",
                               "A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B",
                               "B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B"),
                   Site = c("Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something",
                            "Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something",
                            "Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something",
                            "Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something",
                            "Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something",
                            "Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something",
                            "Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something","Something",
                            "Something","Something","Something","Something"),
                   Mean = c("0.301029995663981","1.07918124604762","0.698970004336019","1.23044892137827","1.53147891704226","1.41497334797082","1.7160033436348",
                            "0.698970004336019","1.39794000867204","1","0.301029995663981","0.301029995663981","0.477121254719662","0.301029995663981","0.301029995663981",
                            "0.301029995663981","0.477121254719662","0.301029995663981","0.301029995663981","0.845098040014257","0.301029995663981","0.301029995663981",
                            "0.477121254719662","0.698970004336019","1.23044892137827","1.41497334797082","1.95904139232109","1.5910646070265","1.53147891704226",
                            "1.14612803567824","1.57978359661681","1.34242268082221","0.778151250383644","0.301029995663981","0.301029995663981","0.477121254719662",
                            "0.301029995663981","1.20411998265592","0.845098040014257","1.17609125905568","1.20411998265592","0.698970004336019","0.301029995663981",
                            "0.698970004336019","0.698970004336019","0.903089986991944","1.14612803567824","0.301029995663981","0.602059991327962","0.301029995663981",
                            "0.845098040014257","0.698970004336019","0.698970004336019","0.301029995663981","0.698970004336019","0.301029995663981","0.301029995663981",
                            "0.301029995663981","0.477121254719662","0.301029995663981","0.301029995663981","0.301029995663981","0.301029995663981","0.301029995663981",
                            "0.602059991327962","0.301029995663981","0.845098040014257","1.92941892571429","1.27875360095283","0.698970004336019","1.38021124171161",
                            "1.20411998265592","1.38021124171161","1.14612803567824","1","1.07918124604762","1.17609125905568","0.845098040014257","0.698970004336019",
                            "0.778151250383644","0.301029995663981","0.845098040014257","1.64345267648619","1.46239799789896","1.34242268082221","1.34242268082221",
                            "0.778151250383644"))

# Set factors
str(data)
data$Date<-as.factor(data$Date)
data$Site<-as.factor(data$Site)
data$Species<-as.factor(data$Species)
data$Mean<-as.numeric(data$Mean)
str(data)

## 2-way ANOVA on trimmed means
t2way(Mean ~ Species*Date, data = data)

## post hoc tests
mcp2atm(Mean ~ Species*Date, data = data)
```

The error message is the following:

```
> t2way(Mean ~ Species*Date, data = data)
Call:
t2way(formula = Mean ~ Species * Date, data = data)

                value p.value
Species        2.6897   0.119
Date         460.4632   0.001
Species:Date  20.9332   0.336

> ## post hoc tests
> mcp2atm(Mean ~ Species*Date, data = data)
Error in smmcrit(df, ncol(con)) : C must be less than or equal to 28
```